# Animate FAB when switching tabs

Tags: android, button, android-studio, slidingmenu

I am currently using [FAB](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) and followed [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) for the Sliding tabs. I want a grow animation as I switch tabs. Thanks

**anim/simple_grow.xml**

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:duration="700"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
</scale>
```

EDIT: 
**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
package adapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created

    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            FactorialTab factorialTab = new FactorialTab();

            return factorialTab;

        } else if(position == 1)             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            PermutationTab permutationTab = new PermutationTab();
            return permutationTab;
        }
        else {
            RandomTab randomTab = new RandomTab();
            return randomTab;
        }
    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package activity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"Factorial", "Permutation", "Random"};
    int Numboftabs = 3;

    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_pressed);
            }
        });

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);    
        fab.show(false);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.simple_grow);

        fab.startAnimation(animation);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I would love to know how to know my position out of ViewPagerAdapter. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //show or hide your fab here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes please - it would be helpful